# I got 403 Forbidden when I try to send Mail using graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I got 403 Forbidden when I try to send Mail using graph API

If I try to login with @gmail or @outlook Id then It's working fine

But recently I've try to send mail with using @hotmail.com domain Id ,In this case I'm able to call receive mail graph API , but got 403 error in case of send mail graph api.

What's the exact Issue ?

I got this response when try to send mail graph API

[image]

There Is issue when I logged with @hotmail domain Id but I'm not able to send Mail , receive Mail functionality works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Below error occurs if office365 license is not available for your subscription

[image]

After using licensed subscription.
This error occurs when the `delegated permissions` are given instead of Application permissions to access the mail.

***`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/xxx/sendMail`***

and Please make sure to login with account that you are a `member` of .

[image]

And have the privileges to send mail.
The guest user may not have access to all the properties and some organizations restrict Hotmail/live accounts .The guest must accept the invite .

Check the user assignment and change the settings accordingly to allow users to send mail.

[image]

And for them, assign proper role to have access privileges.

[image]

Comment: I've use this endpoint for send Mail `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail`

Comment: Which api permissions are given ? delegated or application permissions?

Comment: delegated and I'm also able to send my by using other email ids
Incase of @hotmail.com ID I'm not able to send mail but I'm able to receive mail of this ID

Comment: Delegated permissions wont work with /me endpoint .

Comment: And Can we are able to login using @gmail ID in graph api authorization ? , If I'm try to login on that time I got this error **We couldn't find an account with that username. Try another, or**

Comment: Give mail.send application permissions ,  the user must be approved user , must be a member .

Comment: I have use user.send permission as a scope variable to generate token

Comment: `scope : "user.read Mail.Send Mail.Read Mail.ReadBasic Mail.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access",` I have add this scope in payload to generate token
It's perfectly works for other IDs

Comment: Have you got to check with application permissions granted admin consent.